# PHP: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: php

I'm getting this error on line 15 which is the line where is the PHP closing tag. Kinda weird. Can you see what's wrong ?

```
<?php

$fh = fopen("testfile.txt",'w') or die("failed to create file");

$text = <<<_END
Line one
Line two
Line three
    _END;

fwrite($fh, $text) or die("could not write to file");
fclose($fh);
echo "file 'testfile.txt' written successfully";

?>
```

Comment: works for me in php 7.1.1, what version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 7.0.15

Comment: Strange that it works for you. I tried to run it in online ide and it gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question on social media and one coder chimed in with a suggestion. Remove the white space before closing `_END` tag. Apparently the starting `_END` tag can be indented but the closing tag **must not** be indented otherwise it will throw an error.

When I got rid off the extra tab it worked wonderfully !

Comment: Did you put the fixed version in your question?

Comment: No, so everybody can see the error (indented closing _END tag)

Comment: I'm confused. The `_END` tag in the script in your question is not indented.

Comment: Ah yes any white space there is certainly a problem. But it seems to have been lost in your example, which explains why my copy/paste worked.

Comment: Anyone knows why this topic got "off-topic" tag ??? I correctly used "php" tagging to make clear it's PHP-related. If this website is meant to be Q&As related only to Ubuntu operating system why are there tags like "php", "server", "apache" even available to pick ?

Comment: @MarkAlexa StackOverflow is for generic programming questions like this one. AskUbuntu is for questions specific to Ubuntu. The PHP tag on AskUbuntu is usually for questions about installing and running the PHP interpreter on Ubuntu.